# Display feature reduction Clustering points count ArcGIS js feature layer?

Tags: clustering, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am able to cluster the points in the map using the following code:

```
 var serviceUrl = "https://services.arcgis.com/V6ZHFr6zdgNZuVG0/arcgis/rest/services/Places_of_Worship_India/FeatureServer/0";
    var layer = new FeatureLayer(serviceUrl, {
      outFields: [ "name", "religion", "denomination" ],
      featureReduction: {
        type: "cluster"
      },
      infoTemplate: new PopupTemplate({
        title: "{name}",
        description: "Religion: {religion}"
          + "<br>Denomination: {denomination}"
      })
    });
    map.addLayer(layer);
```

But I need to display cluster points count on top of the cluster image.